# Have to specify return in method, but I want the method to call itself again instead of returning

Tags: java, methods, return

I have written a method. It is imitating flipping a coin and trying to detect a case "three heads in a row". As soon as three heads in a row appears (counter=3), the method returns number of iterations it took to get to this point (genCounter).

The problem is that eclipse says that this method should return "int", but I did return genCounter.(both counter and genCounter are int instance variables). As I understood from browsing the internet, the problem is that I am not returning anything in else. But I don't want it to return anything, in case of else I want to start my method from the beginning.

```
private int isThree(){
    String coin = rg.nextBoolean()?"Heads":"Tails";
    if (coin.equals("Heads")){
        counter += 1;
    }else{
        counter = 0;
    }
    genCounter += 1;
    if (counter == 3) {
        return genCounter;
    }else{
        isThree();
    }
}
```

Comment: every possible state of your function has to return something. in your code if counter == 3 then it returns the counter but it does not return anything in the else condition. add return there.

Comment: You need a `while` loop there, not recursion.

Comment: Not true, you can implement any "iterative" construct using recursion, and avoid inflating the stack using tail-recursion. [This](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) is a great starting point to understand what I am saying.

Comment: *The problem is that eclipse says that this method should return "int"* don't trust all what Eclipse said ;)

Comment: @AndreaRichiardi no tail recursion in Java though, better to avoid recursion because of that.

Comment: @Sam Yes, what you say is true, but I was talking in general as a way to say that you can use recursion here, having OP not specified space/time requirements of what it looks like a programming exercise.

Comment: @AndreaRichiardi certainly nothing wrong with practicing recursion in Java to learn! Ambitious programmers could pick up a [purely functional language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Pure) and practice in a less forgiving environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
return isThree();
```

in the `else` should do it.

Answer (score 6):

> But I don't want it to return anything, in case of else I want to start my method from the beginning.

Hint: to repeat some actions, use a loop (which will also solve your current problem).

You are currently using recursion for this; while doable, it does complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: yeah, I did not learn recursions yet, but I know a little bit about them, so I thought it'd be cool to try them. But you are right, it made things a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @user3349993 for learning purposes, practicing recursion in Java is no prob. When you start producing production code though, Java is not a language optimized for recursion. It can produce very ugly stacktraces and leaves you with code that scales poorly. Here's more infoz about programming w recursion: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149167/are-functional-languages-better-at-recursion

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the method to return the value of the call to itself.  Change:

```
isThree();
```

to

```
return isThree();
```